Spring boot Not initialize dependency
When you call up the main screen, you choose what you want to do, in this I choose to register, when I go to the "opcoesCadastro" class I choose what I want to register, be it a client or a dependent, when I choose client I go to the "cadastroCliente" class in that I call two @Autowired, one for my "Customers" interface where I check whether the customer's email is already registered, an error appears saying that "Cannot invoke "com.dev.spring.repository.Clientes.findByEmail( String)" because "this.clientes" is null"
I'm hoping to be able to check whether the customer's email is already registered or not, but it always gives the error that "this.clientes" is null
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.internews.spring"})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx) {
        return args -> {
            System.out.println("Aplicação de terminal Spring Boot");
            TelaPrincipal project = ctx.getBean(TelaPrincipal.class);
            project.telaPrincipal();
        };
    }
}


@Component
public class Cadastro{
    
    @Autowired
    private Clientes clientes;
    
    @Autowired
    private ClienteController controle;

    public void cadastrarCliente() {
               
         ....
            
            System.out.print("  E-mail: ");
            email = input.nextLine().toLowerCase();

            if (email.equals("0")) {
                System.out.println("> Saindo..");
                input.nextLine();
                return;
            } else if (clientes.findByEmail(email).isPresent()) {
                System.err.println(">> E-mail ja cadastrado.");
                input.nextLine();
            }

       ....

    }

The error happens when reading "clientes.findByEmail(email).isPresent()".
The rest works fine.
Erro:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.internews.spring.repository.Clientes.findByEmail(String)" because "this.clientes" is null
    at com.internews.spring.opcao.Cadastro.cadastrarCliente(Cadastro.java:68) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.internews.spring.tela.TelaCadastro.opcoesCadastro(TelaCadastro.java:45) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.internews.spring.tela.TelaPrincipal.telaPrincipal(TelaPrincipal.java:48) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.internews.spring.Application.lambda$0(Application.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.lambda$callRunner$5(SpringApplication.java:790) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer$1.acceptWithException(ThrowingConsumer.java:83) ~[spring-core-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer.accept(ThrowingConsumer.java:60) ~[spring-core-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer$1.accept(ThrowingConsumer.java:88) ~[spring-core-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:798) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:789) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.lambda$callRunners$3(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:357) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:510) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:342) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at com.internews.spring.Application.main(Application.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]



Good text explanation, but please update the question to add the code which demonstrates the issue.

Sorry @AndrewS , I'm new here.

It's probably the call to project.telaPrincipal(); during bean creation, when not all beans have yet to be created/injected.  Move that call so it is invoked after the app is fully started.  Here is an example.

Thanks for the explanation @AndrewS, try according to the example, adding the annotation @EventListener(Application.class) but the error still persists.
